# Create web source module oracle apex 20.0

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle-apex-20.1

I have one web page name sth like that: 'https://bus/api/check'. When I run this web, it returns data normally. But when I create web source module, it shows me as below

An error occurred during URL invocation.

ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
I search on GG about that problem. I try to solve my problem follow this web:
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6121/index-en.html

It is very clear. I created new wallet named https_wallet and added certificate successfully.  However, I check by select statement on DB, with code:

select APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request(p_url => ''https://bus/api/check',p_http_method => 'GET',p_wallet_path => 'file:C:/temp/wallet/https_wallet',p_wallet_pwd => 'pass_word') from dual;

It shows HTTPS request failed and security violation.**Futhermore, while link api web get certificate from Amazon, I try same step on another web on Google, it is o**k.I don't know why that reason. Can anyone help me to solve my those problem. I do not have much experience in create web source module.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding the user, password (basic or oauth2). or changing the method to POST.
Another idea could be test using postman and check first if the endpoint (url) its correct.